# JavaScript autoclick child node element

Tags: javascript, html, click

I've been endlessly looking for a working way to automate a mouse click on a specific element using javascript (I'm making a user-script). The structure is like the below:

```
<div id="elementContainer">
  <div class="item1" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">AutoClick Here!</div>
</div>
```

**item1** is the thing I want to automate a click on. I've tried lots of approaches, e.g. getting the element and creating/initialising/dispatching a 'click' event on it, calling .click() on it etc, but to be honest I'm new to javascript and don't hugely know what I'm doing!

I can happily get the element and make changes to it (like changing the innerHTML), but want to be able to simulate/automate a click on it too. I would be very grateful for any advice on how to proceed.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: .click() works only on some tags, mainly inputs. If you need to solve simple tasks, you may use AutoIT instead of javascript. Otherwise, you'll need to fire click event.

Comment: The click probably is working, but there is no default click event on a div element.  have you tried binding your own click event to the div?

Comment: Maybe, this works with jQ. With pure JS in userscripts it won't work. Firebug (on this page): $$('div').forEach(function(div){ if (div.click) console.log(div); }); -> nothing

Answer (score 0):

Calling [`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click) on the element should work just fine.

```
var container = document.getElementById('elementContainer'),
    innerDiv = container.getElementsByClassName('item1');
    
innerDiv.click();
```

---

That said:

> The click method is intended to be used with INPUT elements of type button, checkbox, radio, reset or submit. Gecko does not implement the click method on other elements that might be expected to respond to mouse–clicks such as links (A elements), nor will it necessarily fire the click event of other elements.
>
> Non–Gecko DOMs may behave differently.
>
> When a click is used with elements that support it (e.g. one of the INPUT types listed above), it also fires the element's click event which will bubble up to elements higher up the document tree (or event chain) and fire their click events too. However, bubbling of a click event will not cause an A element to initiate navigation as if a real mouse-click had been received.

Have you bound any click event handlers to that `<div>`?

Comment: There is a click handler on the object, something like:

`$('container').addEventListener('click',handleMouseClick,false);`


Does this make a difference to manually firing the event?

Comment: @Steven, you could just call the event handler yourself: `handleMouseClick.apply($('container'))`, or you could [create the event manually](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.createEvent).

Comment: Thanks Matt, my new problem with this method is that as I'm trying to create a userscript - my javascript code is seperate to the javascript code running on the website (that contains the handleMouseClick code)! I'm not sure how/if I can reference such a function from my own code.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents